# How to format body to pass input dataset as parameter in Azure ML?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to consume my Azure ML Pipeline (Batch) from LogicApps. For that, I've deployed the Batch pipeline with the dataset as parameter :[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYhU5.png)

But I can't figure it out, how to format my body to invoke the pipeline and I don't find documentation on that.

For now, this is how my logicapp looks like:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkKCB.png)
and I get a 415 Http Error code when trying to invoke the pipeline.

Thanks for your help.